# Standard notation of proposition in induction?

Tags: notation, induction

I am wondering whether the following notation in mathematical induction is standard.

For example, P(k) is a proposition and we write:

$P(k):\sum_{i=1}^{k}F_i^2=F_{k}F_{k+1}.$

Thank you.

Comment: I'd rather write "Let $P(k)$ be the condition/formula $\sum_{i=1}^{k}F_i^2=F_{k}F_{k+1}$", but $\color{blue}:$ is fine too.

Comment: It  is fine.  Typically one "names" the proposition in early induction proofs, and after a while one stops giving it a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard notation. Yours is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's no canonical choice, but $P$ is usually used to denote a proposition. It's like how $n$ usually denotes a natural number, or $f$ usually represents a function.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the use of $:$ to denote the statement.

Comment: Well in that case I suppose it's just punctuation - I wouldn't really call it a notation